# Changing background image for multiple platforms iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocoapods

I'm still getting my feet wet when it comes to mobile development.

So I'm working on a .xib that has just a plain view controller in it. My graphic designer gave me 6 different background images as separate files to use. One for iPhone 4s, one for 5&5s, one for 6, one for 6+, one for non-retina iPads, and one for the retina iPads. The .xib and the images are in a CocoaPod that functions as a shared library between a few different apps that we make.

My question is this: How do I correctly determine which image to set as the background since the devices that the app can be run on all require different images?

What I've tried so far:

To get the device

```
-(NSString*)deviceName {
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

//I set deviceType to the following return
return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

And then quite a few if statements to set the background image:

```
if ([deviceType compare:@"iPhone3, 1"] == 0) {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone_4"]]];
}
else if ([deviceType compare:@"iPhone5, 4"] == 0) {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone_5"]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specify different images for different screen sizes, one of solutions is name image with screen size height in the end.

For example image "DetailsBackground"

For iPhone 4, 4s - "DetailsBackground480"

iPhone 5, 5s - "DetailsBackground568"

iPhone 6 - "DetailsBackground667"

and so on

And then in code just load image according to your screen bounds:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BackgroundImage%.0f.png", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height];
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

Another solution is using Image Assets.

But it more suitable to portrait/landscape and iPhone/iPad There you can use "Device Specific" + compact\regular\any widht+height in the image properties.

Please check attached screenshot:
[image]

Comment: After I choose which device to deploy it on, how would I choose the correct image in the code? I can make the image "iPhone_4" deployable only on iPhone 4's, but how do I tell it to load "iPhone_4" and not another image in the same folder called "iPhone_6plus"?

Comment: Awesome, that was just what I needed. Thanks for the help, I never would have thought to do it that way!